# Access table structure from hibernate Repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, repository-pattern

How can I access this value, **the max value and message** from the controller

[image]

I try to access the information schema table, do it via sql and access this variable without writing it directly in the code,

[image]

[image]

I was trying to access the schema Information table, to get the maximum value from the column but it generates an error that is not mapped

[image]

thank you very much and sorry, I'm new to this

Comment: try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html?is-external=true

Comment: Perhaps you should **read the documentation** on how to do *native* queries: [Native SQL Queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options to do this.

1. Since the value is constant, you can declare a static final variable and use it as the class variable.
   eg:

`static final int MAX_RANGE = 100;`

In this case, just use "class_name".MAX_RANGE

You could also specify the value in a property file and use the property file as and when needed.

2. You can use reflection (which is not the best case)

   `Class<?> cls = Class.forName(name);
   cls.getDeclaredAnnotations(); // get all annotation
   (cls.getDeclaredMethods()[0]).getAnnotations(); //get annotation of a method
   Annotation ety = cls.getAnnotation(Annotation.class); // get annotation of particular annotation class`

Comment: not sure what the OP is asking for, but it seems like he is asking how to get the databases metadata?

Comment: Do you know that if a variable is `private` as in `private static final int MAX_RANGE = 100;` you can not do `"class_name".MAX_RANGE`

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks for pointing it out. The whole idea was to give options. I am not even sure what the project structure looks like. But anyways thanks